# BiConsumer exception test

Tags: java, code-coverage, junit5

How i can test exception for code coverage. I can mock Connection, but i don't know what to do next

```
 private static final BiConsumer<PreparedStatement, Integer> INTEGER_CONSUMER
            = (PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Integer param) -> {
        try {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, param);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DBException(String.format(MESSAGE_FORMAT, "Integer consumer", FAILED_MESSAGE), e);
        }
    };
```

Comment: We can't see how you're using it in this case.  It _looks_ like you could just mock the `PreparedStatement` to `throw` an `SQLException` when `setInt` is called, but without seeing more it's difficult to say.

Comment: How are you calling that `BiConsumer`?